# Nunit Test Order - Single Test - Multiple Orders

Tags: nunit

For Nunit Test order, is it possible to have multiple order positions for a test, such as [Test, Order(3, 10, #...)]?

Scenario - I am automating a multi-page online application using end-to-end ordered tests (with Asserts verifying entered info), and I want to verify info on previous pages is still there - saved - when I click *Back* button (basically, reverse-check the end-to-end starting from last page of application using *Back* button to navigate). I want to reuse Asserts already there instead of rewriting the same ones again.
I have tried the following as an experiment, which generate build error CS1729 - 'type' does not contain a constructor that takes 'number' arguments:
[Test, Order(66, 67)]
**
[Test, Order(66)(67)]
**
[Test, Order(66), Order(67)]
**
[Test, Order(66)]
[Test, Order(67)]

I Googled this, and I don't see anything that does the above, so I assume it is not possible, but want to confirm. I cannot remove the Order attribute as that's part of the requirement for this test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that's not possible. The `OrderAttribute` sets a property, which is a simple integer.

To simulate the effect you want, you may do the following:

1. Extract all the code of the test in question to a separate method, called by the test. It should have the same signature as the test.
2. Replicate the test you want to repeat, using a different name.
3. Assign a different order attribute to  each test.

Assuming a signature of `void TestMethod()` it will look something like this...

```
[Test, Order(66)]
public void MyTest66()
{
    MyRealTest();
}

[Test, Order(67)]
public void MyTest67()
{
    MyRealTest();
}

private void MyRealTest()
{
    // Your actual test code goes here
}
```

Note... this is a **really ugly hack** but the only guaranteed way I can think of to do what you indicate is required.

Comment: to ensure I understand, it is NOT possible to traverse "back" through NUnit Ordered tests, i.e., do the ordered tests in reverse order, correct?
The only way to go back  through the end-to-end flow would be to do a separate test that does this, per your suggestion, yes?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Can you please give your inputs ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71576396/test-explorer-runs-all-test-cases-instead-of-selected-ones-when-number-of-test-c